# pending transaction on eth blockchain

Tags: cpp-ethereum

i still waiting from 4h for my transaction. I know de gwei is low but what you think it will be processed.

0xb69c181d38bcd157d07a623b5c1b620e6694644626bc1ed48e984ed089933e86

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, services such as EthGasStation's [Tx Calculator](https://ethgasstation.info/calculatorTxV.php) will provide you with an time estimate for you transaction to be mined into a block, given a specific gas price.

For your transaction - 47 Gwei - it gives a mean time of 15986 seconds, which is ~4.5 hours. But that's no guarantee that it will be mined in that time, merely an estimate of the mean based on similarly priced transactions and the current state of the market.